# plotting bounded CDF of discrete count data in matplotlib python

Tags: python, graph, plot, matplotlib

I have a numpy array "data" that just contains a set of integer counts. Given another array "bins", I just want to make a frequency plot/CDF of the fraction of total entries in "data" that have at least bins[0]-many counts, at least bins[1]-many counts, etc. and make it into a bar plot, in matplotlib. For example, if:

```
data = [1, 4, 5, 10]
bins = [0, 5, 6, 7]
```

then the result should be a bar graph that has 0, 5, 6, 7 on the x-axis and then the fraction of data that has values >= 0, then values >= 5, etc.  How can I make this kind of "discrete" CDF bar plot with specified bins in matplotlib?  Thanks.

Comment: The question body describes not the CDF, but 1-CDF. That's a bit confusing after reading the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using matplotlib I assume you are also using numpy, so you can just go through `bins` and work out the fraction of `data` such that `data>bin`, for all `data` in `datas` and for all `bin` in `bins`.

To that effect this could work:

```
import numpy as np
# turn data into numpy array for easier manipulation
data2 = np.array(data)
n     = len(data2)

# calculate fractions for each bin in bins
# astype('float') because otherwise you end up doing integer arithmetic
fracs = [ sum(data2>=bin).astype('float')/n for bin in bins ]
```

Now just plot `bins` against `fracs`, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(bins,fracs)
plt.show()
```

Comment: For convenience: see `numpy.cumsum`.

Comment: @SteveTjoa: since cumsum does not take a "bins" argument, how could it be used here instead? It seems relevant but I cannot see it, if you have an example that would be great.